# AWS Amplify Auth.federatedSignIn can't use received authorization code

Tags: amazon-web-services, authorization, aws-amplify, federated-identity, aws-amplify-cli

So I want add a federated sign in feature for my website app, instead of using the hosted UI I want to create my own UI for the sign in process. So I used Auth.federatedSignIn({provider: 'Facebook'}).

Weird thing is I can get the tokens from the TOKEN endpoint ('POST [https://mydomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token'](https://mydomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token%27)) using the authorization code I received after federation by hosted UI.
But I kept getting invalid_request from the endpoint when I used the authorization code I received from Auth.federatedSignIn({provider: 'Facebook'}). And the POST requests from both methods are exactly the same.

```
            axios.post(`https://mydomainnnnnauth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token`, qs.stringify({
            grant_type: "authorization_code",
            code: myauthorizationcode,
            client_id: "myclientid",
            redirect_uri: "https://mydomainnnnn/callback/"
        }), {
            headers: {
                "content-type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        })
```

I have been at it for many days, I don't know what's wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "aws-amplify" its automatically sends post request to "https://mydomainnnnnauth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token" endpoint once you land the callback page.

check the network tab. You will see an additional post request.

Once the authorization code is used it cannot reuse. then the response is invalid because the token is already used.

Follow this steps

1. To prevent automatically sending post request
   comment redirectSignIn, property in amplify auth configuration object as follows

```js
 const cognitoConfigs={
    region: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_REGION,
    userPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_USER_POOL_ID,
    userPoolWebClientId: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_WEB_CLIENT_ID,
    mandatorySignIn: false,
    oauth: {
      domain: 'domain',
      scope: ['email', 'profile', 'openid'],
      //**redirectSignIn: 'https://example.com/cb/'**, **COMMENT THIS**
      redirectSignOut: 'http://localhost:3000',
      responseType: 'code' 
  }
  }
```

2. Then send the post requet